# Get objects whose fields are marked with attributes

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, reflection, attributes

guys, i'm writing now something like 'databse system' (orm?) with Unity3D using MySQL. I've come up with a structure for this system so that different entities don't know about existence of my database and they 'live their lives'.

So i've got now one problem.

For instance:

We have following class, just an example:

```
public class Planet
{
    [Key("planets")]
    [Table("planets","name")]
    public string name;

    [Table("planets", "temperature")]
    public string temperature;
}
```

Something like this. And We also have remote singleton table object called 'Table':

```
class Table
{
    public string tableName = "planets";
    public static List<Planet> observables = new List<Planet>();

    public string[,] data;
    public string[] columns;

    public Table()
    {
        columns = new string[] {"name", "temperature"};
        data = new string[,] { { "mars", "venus", "jupiter" },
                               { "-40", "450", "20000" } };
    }

   //finding objcets logic goes here
}
```

I know how to handle all entitie's fields marked with attributes but the only thing i have to obtain is possibility to **receive all my objects with fields decorated by attributes**. So how can my Table receive all my Planets instances at any moment not having changed our Planet class.???

I hope i've described problem distinctly and sorry for my horrible English
Thanks in advance!

Comment: with "Planets instances" do you mean your online gameobject assets?

Comment: doesn't matter. i need to get all System.Objets and GameObjects

Comment: Can you clarify the "receive all my objects with fields decorated by attributes" part a bit more? Imo, you wan't to get all the instances oftype `Planet` where the fields are decorated with an attribute. But isn't that the case all the time?